# Creating Mysql Procedure

Tags: mysql

I need help little. I have three tables in mysql.

- Products
- Customers
- SellingPrices

Normally i have query in my classic asp file its in bottom.

```
set rs1=db.execute("Select id from customers order by id desc")

DO WHILE NOT rs1.EOF

set rs2=db.execute("Select id from products where order by id desc")

DO WHILE NOT rs2.EOF 

set rs3=db.execute("Select id from sellingprices where product_id="&rs2("id")&" and customer_id="&rs1("id")&" and status=1")
if rs3.eof then
db.Execute("INSERT INTO selling prices (price,product_id,status,customer_id) VALUES ('0','"&rs2("id")&"','1','"&rs1("id")&"');")
end if

rs3.close
Set rs3= Nothing

rs2.MoveNext
LOOP
rs2.close
Set rs2= Nothing

rs1.MoveNext
LOOP
rs1.close
Set rs1= Nothing
```

My question is how can i create stored procedure for this with Mysql?

Comment: You may achieve this in Single query. Please check: [`INSERT .. SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong

```
Select id from products where order by id desc
```

will give errors, after the `where` you should have something to compare and you don't have that.

Solution is to remove the `where`, assuming the rest of your code is correct.

```
Select id from products order by id desc
```

Comment: I gave example it works with classic asp but I want to create stored procedure